# Allow Amazon S3 <AllowedOrigin> both http and www?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am using Amazon S3 and have this in my "Edit CORS Configuration"

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

I want to restrict  to my domain.

Without www, I can only access with http and not www

```
<AllowedOrigin>http://domain.com</AllowedOrigin>
```

With www, I can only access with www and not only http

```
<AllowedOrigin>www.domain.com</AllowedOrigin>
```

This is not working with wildcard

```
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*.domain.com</AllowedOrigin>
```

or

```
<AllowedOrigin>*.domain.com</AllowedOrigin>
```

How should I write my `<AllowedOrigin>` to allow both http://domain.com and http://www.domain.com? Do I need to have two `<CORSRule>`?